# How do I display output text in a TextArea?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a Heads or Tails game in Java at the moment and I'm struggling with getting the output text into my text area.

What I have is at the moment is:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) 
        System.out.println("Heads");
    else
        System.out.println("Tails"); 
    jTextArea1.update(jTextArea1.getGraphics());
}
```

I'm trying to make sure when the button is pressed it displays but to no avail. It's been bugging me for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

`System.out` doesn't go to any text area. It's the standard out (although you could redirect it, but let's not get into that here). Use `jTextArea1.setText("Heads");` to update the textarea contents. For appending you'll need to get the existing text first.